Meaning of @{} in tabular declaration
What is the meaning of @{} in the following tabular declaration ?
\begin{tabular} { @{} l@{} } 

\end{tabular}

For instance, to have some lines of text, I use
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment {ditura} { }

  {
    \begin {flushright}
      \begin{tabular} { @{} l@{} }
  }

  {
      \end{tabular}
    \end {flushright}}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin {document}

\begin {ditura}
  Likku Cirillu \\
  Puppi Grillu
\end {ditura}

\end {document}


Note: The syntax is actualy @{...} where ... can be anything in horizontal mode, e.g. \hspace{1cm}, my text, etc. ... will be inserted in between the columns, replacing the default space of 2\tabcolsep (each adjacent column of a separation contributes one \tabcolsep.

Off-topic: \ExplSyntaxOn \ExplSyntaxOff are not necessary in your case.

Somewhat off-topic: why do you have a one column tabular?

@Gargantuar well, without \ExplSyntaxOn \ExplSyntaxOff there would be several spaces hanging around...

One column tabular to have a set of lines all aligned to the left and printed on the right side of a page.  But perhaps there is a better implementation ?

I suggest picking a book on Latex, e.g. this online book, read and try: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables

In a tabular, @{} suppresses column padding(1) (let's call it pad) and substitutes it with its argument. In a tabular, if you have n columns c₁ c₂ it will use "pad c₁ pad pad c₂ pad" when typesetting.
Try:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
|\begin{tabular} { l }
    one \\ two \\
\end{tabular}|
|\begin{tabular} { l l }
    one & one\\ two & two\\
\end{tabular}|

|\begin{tabular} { @{} l@{} }
    one \\ two \\
\end{tabular}|
|\begin{tabular} { @{} l @{} l @{}}
    one & one\\ two & two\\
\end{tabular}|


|\begin{tabular} { @{A} l@{B} }
    one \\ two \\
\end{tabular}|
\end{document}


(1) Thanks to @Mico's comment

What is an intercolumn space?  I want to have one column.  Why does one need two @{} ?

because there is space before and after a column.

Does this mean that there is one table with one column, with no spacing before and after the single column ? Why does one do   l@{} on the second ?

@Bulldrive l is the column. It means the contents will be left-aligned and typeset at its natural width i.e. the column will be as wide as the content needs.

So more clearly, one has @{} l @{}. Right ?

@Bulldrive I added vertical bars to delimit the tabular and a bit more explaining... I hope it's clearer now.

I think I understand.  For a two column tabular, the two entries are separated by the letter B when using { @{A} c @{B} c @{C} }

@Bulldrive yes this is very basic syntax it should be in any latex tutorial such as https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-08

Correct but those do not show @{A} specifically.

@Bulldrive - The term "inter-column whitespace" may have thrown you off. If so, the term "whitespace padding" may be more helpful. By default, LaTeX inserts whitespace (in the amount given by the parameter \tabcolsep) on both sides of each and every column. As a result, by default, there's whitespace padding in the amount of \tabcolsep to the left of the first column and to the right of the final column, and 2\tabcolsep of whitespace between columns. Hence, {@{} cc @{}} means "no whitespace padding at the tabular's edges and normal whitespace padding between columns 1 and 2".
